# I've got 404 error code if I replace value in a payload when using Faraday gem to call request

Tags: ruby, faraday

I am learning Ruby programming and I am building an API testing project. I have a request to a specific site and I am using Faraday gem.
Here my code:

```
conn = Faraday.new
f_response = conn.post do |req|
  req.url 'https://api.abcxyz.vn/v2/tokens'
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  req.body = '{"email": "xxx@gmail.com","password": "abc123","grant_type": "password"}'
end
```

The request is OK and I got the successfull code 201 as I expected.
But I do not understand the format of `req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'`. Is it a hash or array. Because if I replace my code as following:

```
request_headers = {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}
conn = Faraday.new
f_response = conn.post do |req|
  req.url 'https://api.abcxyz.vn/v2/tokens'
  req.headers = request_headers
  req.body = '{"email": "xxx@gmail.com","password": "abc123","grant_type": "password"}'
end
```

The result 404 error code. Woud you please help me out with this case.
Pluse I have another API which requires the 'X-Access-Token' attched in the header fields. 
How can I input it into the payload.

Answer (score 0):

req.headers is a Hash, but by using `req.headers =` you are wiping out any headers that Faraday has set automatically such as 'User-Agent'.  To add new headers, do the same that you've done for 'Content-Type':

```
conn = Faraday.new
f_response = conn.post do |req|
  req.url 'https://api.abcxyz.vn/v2/tokens'
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  req.headers['X-Access-Token'] = 'x-access-token-goes-here'
  req.body = '{"email": "xxx@gmail.com","password": "abc123","grant_type": "password"}'
end
```